# Added two groups to library permissions, then couldn't add any more

Tags: permissions, groups, library

I started adding groups to one of my libraries and it allowed me to add two, then wouldn't let me add anymore.  [image: Two groups added]

I went to site settings, permissions, add group, and created the SharePoint group "Managers toolbox Visitors 3 because SharePoint REALLY sucks".
[image: Created group]

I go in to add the group from all of the groups I've created: [image: Attempting to add group]

But, I'm getting this error everytime I attempt to add a group to my library permissions.[image: Error]

Why did it allow me to add two libraries, and create a bunch more but not add any more?
Thank you.

[image: correlation ID translation item 1]
[image: correlation ID translation item 2]
[image: correlation ID translation item 3]

Comment: Do you have server access to look up the Correlation ID?

Comment: Yes and no.  I do, but due to another permissions issue, I'm unable to access it.  I tried to recreate this in our test environment, and ran into a similar situation, except this time it won't allow me to add ANY of the three created groups.  I ran the correlation ID through Management Shell then ULS Viewer and it gave me these results:

Comment: (see original post)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a simple compatibility issue.  I went to Tools, Compatibility View Settings, and Selected Add to add the website.  That resolved the error and allowed me to add a group.